# Calculate log base 2 recursion

Tags: java

i'm creating recursion method that calculate Log base 2. for log*(1) = should be 0. log*(4) = should be 2. but my method only print out zero and i couldn't figure out the problem.can some one help me?

```
public static int logCalculator(double n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + logCalculator(n * n);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `logCalculator`? EDIT: By the way, please note that the else branch will lead to a stack overflow since you'll never reach the `return 0` anymore.

Comment: `n * n` is _not_ the number you should be calling this with.  (And also, taking a `double` argument isn't going to help either.)

Comment: I'm confused, if you call `logCalculator(4)` you won't get `0`, you'll get a stack overflow exception, since your recursion will never terminate.  For that matter, how is this ever supposed to terminate?  No non-one number, when successively squared, will ever converge to one.

Comment: Looks like infinite loop if `n!=1` thus StackOverflow to me

Comment: If you're wondering what the problem is with comparing `double n` to `1`, read this: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

This will work for base 2 logs

```
public static int logCalculator1(double n) {
    if (n < 2)
       return 0;
    return 1 + logCalculator1(n / 2);
}
```

NOTE: this will round down always and with high numbers is inaccurate, in addition you can make it for all bases like this:

```
public static int logCalculator(int base, double n) {
        if (base > 0) {
            if (n < base) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1 + logCalculator(base, (int)(n / base));
            }
        } return 0;
      }
```

Comment: but can you golf it ?

Comment: This isn't going to work if you call, say, `logCalculator(1.5)`.  Fix the argument type.

Comment: OP had his function return an int so i am also returning an int, if you think i should change it to a double tell me (i am new here so i just fixed the function he had and not created my own better one)